# Miniatured-page-links

Tags: links, page

Suppose that you have a set of 4 pages: A, B, C and D. Each one has drawings and text of their own. I need for the page 5 to be a composition of A, B, C and D such as:

[image]

I'd like for it to be linked, so if I made any change in one of them it would just adjust by itself. I don't even know if it's possible, but thought I could ask. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To generate the last page "linked" to the original pages A, B, C, and D, you must store the content of those pages and reuse the same stored content  to build the last page.

We will define four boxes (`\newsavebox`), save them (`\savebox`) with the content of each page and use them in the corresponding place (`\usebox`).

Since the content of each page will have several paragraphs, we encapsulate it in a parbox `\parbox{\linewidth}{<page content>}`.

Finally we build the last page reusing the boxes. To make the boxes fit in a 2x2 array we scale them `\scalebox{<factor>}{<box>}`.

Any changes made to any of the boxes will be reflected on the corresponding page and on the last page.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\newsavebox{\PageA}
\savebox{\PageA}{% to page A
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \vspace*{50pt}
    
    text A
    
    Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori.
}}
    
\newsavebox{\PageB}
\savebox{\PageB}{%to page B
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \vspace*{50pt}
    
    text B
    
    As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
    in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
    representation of time. Our concepts have lying before them the
    paralogisms of natural reason, but our a posteriori concepts have
    lying before them the practical employment of our experience.
}}

\newsavebox{\PageC}
\savebox{\PageC}{%to page C
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \vspace*{50pt}
    
    text C
    
Therefore, we can deduce that the objects in space and
time (and I assert, however, that this is the case) have lying before
them the objects in space and time. Because of our necessary ignorance
of the conditions, it must not be supposed that, then, formal logic
(and what we have alone been able to show is that this is true) is a
representation of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical
conditions, but the discipline of pure reason, in so far as this
expounds the contradictory rules of metaphysics, depends on the
Antinomies. 

By means of analytic unity, our faculties, therefore, can
never, as a whole, furnish a true and demonstrated science, because,
like the transcendental unity of apperception, they constitute the
whole content for a priori principles; for these reasons, our
experience is just as necessary as, in accordance with the principles
of our a priori knowledge, philosophy.
}}

\newsavebox{\PageD}
\savebox{\PageD}{% to page D
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image}
    \vspace*{50pt}
    
    text D
    
    Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori. \vspace*{50pt}
    
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image}
}}
    

\begin{document}
\centering  
    \usebox{\PageA}
    \clearpage
    
    \usebox{\PageB}
    \clearpage
    
    \usebox{\PageC}
    \clearpage
    
    \usebox{\PageD}
    \clearpage
    
    \scalebox{0.45}{\usebox{\PageA}}\hfill\scalebox{0.45}{\usebox{\PageB}} %first row
    
    \vspace*{100pt}
    
    \scalebox{0.4}{\usebox{\PageC}}\hfill\scalebox{0.55}{\usebox{\PageD}} %second row
\end{document}
```